# How to implement "INSERT INTO" in access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I'm getting a syntax error and am unable to save my database. The syntax error is supposedly in "CREATE TABLE" but "INSERT" is what gets highlighted.

```
 CREATE TABLE courses 
    (
    classid integer primary key, 
    name varchar (50), 
    coursenum char(4), 
    credhours integer
    );

 CREATE TABLE takes_courses
    (
    id integer references students(id),
    classid integer references courses (classid),
    semcode char(4)
    );

    INSERT INTO takes_courses
    (id, classid, semcode)
    VALUES
    (500, 1001, "FA14")

    INSERT INTO takes_courses
    (id, classid, semcode)
    VALUES
    (501, 1002, "FA14")

    INSERT INTO takes_courses
    (id, classid, semcode)
    VALUES
    (501, 1003, "SP15")

    INSERT INTO takes_courses
    (id, classid, semcode)
    VALUES
    (502, 1008, "FA15")
```

Comment: Can you share the DDL for your `courses` table?

Comment: I am honestly not what a DDL is. I tried googling it and found myself confused. DDL's were not covered in class. Sorry... But maybe that could be a step toward me knowing what I am doing wrong?

Comment: If it helps, I have created two other tables. Should I post those?

Comment: `DDL` is short for Data Definition Language - i.e., any SQL statement that creates database objects (e.g., `create table`). Your first statement is a `create table` statement that creates the `takes_courses` table with foreign keys to the `courses` table. In order to understand the problem better, I asked to see the statement you used to create that table.

Comment: I used create table for each

CREATE TABLE courses
(
classid integer primary key,
name varchar (50),
coursenum char(4),
credhours integer
);


I also cannot figure out how to mark that as code in a comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You reported *"The syntax error is supposedly in "CREATE TABLE" but "INSERT" is what gets highlighted."*

That could happen if the `INSERT` and `CREATE TABLE` statements are both contained in the same Access query.

But Access will not let you combine multiple statements and execute them as a batch.  So you must use a separate query for each statement and execute each separately.